# ng-list split with blank delimiter

Tags: angularjs, split, angular-nglist

is there a way to have ng-list split in the same way `string.split('')`(a blank string for the delimiter) would? the split() function splits everything when it is a blank string meaning `'hello world'.split('')` would return `['h','e','l','l','0',' ','w','o','r','l','d']` however when i plug a blank string into ng-list it defaults back to its default delimiter of ", " is there any way to get the behavior im looking for from ng-list? I've already tried this

```
<textarea ng-model='text' ng-list='' ng-trim='false'></textarea>
```

an example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lar0yb8c/)

Comment: Not possible with ngList. Write your own version of the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very pretty way of doing it but by removing the default of ", " in the angular.js file (line 24,620 in version 1.4.8) means that the default becomes an empty string allowing this to work.

Update 
There's also a loophole that allows this but it's a bit of an oddity. The theory is you set the delimiter to a space but then set the ng-trim to true meaning it trims away the space and makes a blank delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Ng-list does not give you the split with empty string.

 But this is easy to achieve with simple javascript.


 Javascript code:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('app',function(){
this.textArry=[];
this.text="";
this.getText=function(){
    console.log(this.text);
};

this.splitWIthNothing=function(){
    this.textArry=this.text.split("");
}
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<div ng-controller='app as a'>
{{a.textArry}}
<textarea ng-model='a.text' ng-change='a.splitWIthNothing()'></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```